# How to store tomcat Server Start/Stop time in database

Tags: java, tomcat, server, liferay, liferay-7

Use case:
Whenever we start/stop the tomcat server, it should log entry into database.

Explanation:
Assume we start the server 12:00, then it should make a entry into database Server1 start 12:00
and if shutdown at 01:00 then make a entry into database Server1 stop 01:00

I tried to figure out some way, but nothing solid which can we implemented.
Do let me know any solution to build this scenario.

I need this for Liferay Tomcat Server

Comment: Well, a simple solution might be to run a program that grabs the times from the logs and puts them into the DB.

Comment: Another option might be to implement a `LifecycleListener` and hook into the startup and shutdown events.

Comment: Did you mean you want to log literally when Tomcat itself goes up & down? Or do you want to know when your web app goes up/down? (One Tomcat instance can have one or more web apps.)

Comment: Please [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824)

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the operating system that this should happen on - if you're on Linux, you're most likely using a script that starts tomcat as background-daemon, and you can easily script such an operation into the startup script.

The daemon script probably even calls tomcat's own `startup.sh` or `catalina.sh` script, so that you could augment them. Just make sure you keep your changes at hand in case of an upgrade that would overwrite those files.

This reduces your problem to "writing to a database from a bash script". And solving that problem would require to know your database